# Let P be a singly linked list. Let Q be the pointer to an intermediate node x in the list, then how to delete x from list?

Tags: algorithm

What is the worst-case time complexity of the best-known algorithm to delete the node x from the list ?

According to me it should be O(1) :

Algo:

Q -> data = Q ->next -> data; // Copy the value of next node into Q.

del = Q -> next; // take another pointer variable pointing to next node of Q.

Q -> next = Q -> next ->next;

free (del);

So what is the issue in this , The links I have gone through , it is given O(n)

http://geeksquiz.com/gate-gate-it-2004-question-13/

Comment: http://gateoverflow.in/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=3750350253357524127

Comment: actually you're approach **does** work and is way more elegant than the one presented on "geeksquiz". The reason why geeksforgeeks selected the `O(n)`-solution is that your approach doesn't work for the last node of the list. Strange though that the last node is considered intermediate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments on the question, this exact question is being asked. The answer is:

> [this] doesn't work for the case when the node to be deleted is last node

The solution you presented won't work for the last node, since no successor is available to this node. Why this matters for "intermediate" nodes isn't entirely clear to me as well, but that's the official answer.

Comment: But it is already given that the node to be deleted is an intermediate node , it is not the last node as already given in the question itself

Comment: @RadhaGogia as i've already mentioned in the answer: I don't get that part as well, but that's the official answer